# Returning only the portion of a line after a matching pattern

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep

I have a file (`file_name`) which contains exactly one occurance of the string `Result:`, at the start of a line. I want to print all the characters after the string `Result:` in that line until I encounter a space. Which shell command should I use?

```
grep "Result: " file_name | tail -c +9
```

is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `awk`.

```
awk '/^Result: / {print $2}' file_name
```

That matches lines that begin with `Result:`, and prints the second field in the file, as defined by the default $IFS, which is whitespace.

Comment: There is a blank behind the colon `:` and afaik, the word before the next colon is searched.

Comment: the OP doesn't mention a second colon.  Just that the string ocurring between `Result: ` and the next space are what is desired.  Awk will by default break up the line on white space. `$1` = "Result:", $2 = the next *word*.  Which is what the OP requested to extract.

Comment: Sorry - I meant 'before the next `blank`'. Your command results for the line `Result:two bla nk` in `bla`.

Comment: I have updated my example to specifically include the space after the colon following `Result: `.   This will now ignore lines like that in your example, and more closely match the initial request of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like what you want is:

```
sed -ne 's/^Result: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file_name
```

Matches against the line with "Result: " and prints the first *word* after it. Other lines are not displayed.

Comment: The OP stated that "Result: " has only one occurrence in the file.  It could be anchored with `^`, but is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
tillblank=$(egrep -o "^Result: [^ ]* " file)
echo ${tillblank/*:/}
```

egrep -o only outputs the pattern you searched for. The next line removes everything up to the colon.

Comment: The OP asks to get only the word after "Result: ", not the entire line.

Comment: Yes - the first line one grabs the matching pattern, and the second line removes the "Result: " from the beginning. Doesn't it work for you? What do you get?

Comment: If the line is `Result: 2 apples`, then your's would get `2 apples`, not `2` as the OP suggested.

Comment: No. egrep -o only grabs `Result: 2` - the second line removes the `Result:`. Did you test it? You should!