# Replacing XML entity values with positive lookaround

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to do some pretty simple `sed`ding of a file:

```
sed 's:(?<=<Type>)default(?=</Type>):super:' < myfile.xml
```

The concept's pretty simple, using positive lookaround, find the tags and replace the contents with "super". Unfortunately, it doesn't work, nothing is replaced. What am I doing wrong?

I'm looking to "edit" a file similar to this:

```
<Hello>
    <World>
        <Type>default</Type>
    </World>
</Hello>
```

so that it looks like this:

```
<Hello>
    <World>
        <Type>super</Type>
    </World>
</Hello>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the input you have and the output you expect? You know that `(`, `)` and `?` have no special meaning in `sed` if not escaped.

Comment: Input: `<Type>default</Type>`, expected output: `<Type>super</Type>`. I have to escape my parentheses? Why?

Comment: So why do you put `(?<=` in the pattern if this is not present in the input?

Comment: Positive lookbehind? Make sure that <Type> matches before the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct, but `sed` does not handle lookarounds. Your code works fine with `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's:(?<=<Type>)default(?=</Type>):super:' your.file
```

As regular expressions are generally not really good in XML handling, I suggest to try [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```sh
xml ed -O -u '//Type' -v 'super' your.file
```

Both `perl` and `xml` can do in-place editing too, so adds no pain replacing `sed`.

Comment: Now I understand what was strange to me in the OP `sed` script: it uses `perl` syntax in `sed`, and I don't know `perl`. Thanks to clarify.

Comment: Thank you! You understood what I was trying to do :) That's EXACTLY what I meant!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use Perl regular expression syntax in sed; this won't work. Sed uses [basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions); Perl uses [extended regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) with [more features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Perl-derived_regular_expressions). Lookaround is one of the Perl-specific features; it's found in other modern regexp implementations, but not in sed.

You don't need lookaround here. Positive lookaround at the beginning or end of a pattern you're replacing can easily be turned into a variable replacement text. See also [Return only the portion of a line after a matching pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern/24151#24151) for more examples and explanations.

```
sed 's:\(<Type>\)default\(</Type>\):\1super\2:'
```

Here, since the look-behind and look-ahead are constant, you could even do a simple string replacement.

```
sed 's:<Type>default</Type>:<Type>super</Type>:'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand clearly which parts of the input are variable and which are constant. Supposing `Type` is variable and `default`, `super` are constants, you can use the following `sed` script

```
s:<\([^>]\+\)>default</\1>:<\1>super</\1>:
```