# Pass the output of previous command to next as an argument

Tags: command-line, pipe, arguments, command-substitution, output

I've a command that outputs data to stdout (`command1 -p=aaa -v=bbb -i=4`).
The output line can have the following value:

```
rate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps
```

I want to grep that output in order to store that 'rate' (I guess pipe will be useful here).
And finally, I would like that rate to be a value of a parameter on a second command (let's say `command2 -t=${rate}`)

It looks to be tricky on my side; I would like to know better how to use pipes, grep, sed and so on.

I've tried lots of combinations like that one but I'm getting confused of these:

```
$ command1 -p=aaa -v=bbb -i=4 | grep "rate" 2>&1 command2 -t="rate was "${rate}
```

Comment: Hard to fathom that this has no accepted answer after over 9 years.

Comment: @JesseAdelman that's entirely due to the asker failing to select one. [Unix.SE] reports they haven't logged in for over nine years so you're unlikely to see one accepted now

Answer (score 236):

You are confusing two very different types of inputs.

1. Standard input (`stdin`)
2. Command line arguments

These are different, and are useful for different purposes. Some commands can take input in both ways, but they typically use them differently. Take for example the `wc` command:

1. Passing input by `stdin`:

   ```
   ls | wc -l
   ```

   This will count the lines in the output of `ls`
2. Passing input by command line arguments:

   ```
   wc -l $(ls)
   ```

   This will count lines *in the list of files* printed by `ls`

Completely different things.

To answer your question, it sounds like you want to capture the rate from the output of the first command, and then use the rate as a command line argument for the second command. Here's one way to do that:

```
rate=$(command1 | sed -ne 's/^rate..\([0-9]*\)%.*/\1/p')
command2 -t "rate was $rate"
```

Explanation of the `sed`:

- The `s/pattern/replacement/` command is to replace some pattern
- The pattern means: the line must start with "rate" (`^rate`) followed by any two character (`..`), followed by 0 or more digits, followed by a `%`, followed by the rest of the text (`.*`)
- `\1` in the replacement means the content of the first expression captured within `\(...\)`, so in this case the digits before the `%` sign
- The `-n` flag of the `sed` command means to not print lines by default. The `p` at the end of the `s///` command means to print the line if there was a replacement. In short, the command will print something only if there was a match.

Comment: No, it would be useful to have what OP asked - many times we don't get to control how a tool passes its output or accepts its input. Some decided via stdin/out, some uses arguments. It'd be very useful to have a way to glue those different tools together.

Comment: @KFL see my answer gluing together with pipes and xargs

Comment: What about this answer doesn't answer the original question? It feels like, even if it has more info than was directly requested, gives good options to ponder.

Comment: @JesseAdelman It's a great answer, but I think KFL wanted to see the answer explicitly pipe the two into a single command

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Yah. It seems a shame to have someone ask a question like "How can I build a house made of straw, but made of bricks?", and get good answers about building a house with bricks, but get the answerer's unrewarded for their answers. That said, I don't claim to know how to resolve that situation...

Answer (score 106):

I tend to use this:

```
command1 | xargs -I{} command2 {}
```

Pass output of `command1` through xargs using substitution (the braces) to `command2`. If command1 is `find` be sure to use `-print0` and add `-0` to `xargs` for null terminated strings and `xargs` will call `command2` for each thing found.

In your case (and taking the sed line from @janos):

```
command1 -p=aaa -v=bbb -i=4 | sed -ne 's/^rate..\([0-9]*\)%.*/\1/p' | xargs -I{} command2 -t="rate was {}"
```

Answer (score 6):

I generally use `command` to place it's output as argument to another command. For e.g., to find resource consumed by process foo on freebsd will be:

```
procstat -r `pgrep -x foo`
```

Here, pgrep is used to extract the PID of process foo which is passed to procstat command which expects PID of process as argument.

Answer (score 5):

To simulate the output of `command1` I am using this echo statement:

```
$ echo -e "Foo\nrate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps\nBar"
$ alias command1='echo -e "Blah\nrate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps\nBlag"'
```

A quick test:

```
$ command1
Blah
rate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps
Blag
```

Thats all good, so lets parse it out:

```
$ command1 | grep 'rate'
rate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps
```

So we get the line we want out of `command1`, lets pass that into `command2`:

```
$ alias command2='echo'
$ command2 -t="rate was "$(command1 | grep 'rate')
-t=rate was rate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps
```

I'm expecting `"rate was "$(command1 | grep 'rate')` to concatenate automatically.
If that doesn't work because of whitespace, you should be able to pass the input like so instead:

```
$ alias command2='echo'
$ command2 -t=$(echo '"rate was ' $(command1 | grep 'rate') '"')
-t="rate was rate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps "
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) & [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) :

```
command | grep -oP '\$>\s+rate\s+\(\K[^\)]+'
```

Comment: So `grep` will just output some value but the question is how to use that value as a parameter of another command. Unfortunately, that important part is missing in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first task is to extract the rate from that line. With GNU grep (non-embedded Linux or Cygwin), you can use the `-o` option. The part you want is the one containing only digits, and followed by a `%` sign. If you don't want to extract the `%` itself, you need an additional trick: a [zero-width lookahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3dpattern)), which matches nothing but only if that nothing is followed by `%`.

```
command1 -p=aaa -v=bbb -i=4 | grep -o -P '[0-9]+(?=%)'
```

Another possibility is to use sed. To extract a part of a line in sed, use the `s` command, with a regex that matches the whole line (starting with `^` and ending with `$`), with the part to retain in a group (`\(…\)`). Replace the whole line by the content of the group(s) to keep. In general, pass the `-n` option to turn off default printing and put the `p` modifier to print lines where there is something to extract (here there's a single line so it doesn't matter). See [Return only the portion of a line after a matching pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern/24151#24151) and [Extracting a regex matched with 'sed' without printing the surrounding characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31476/extracting-a-regex-matched-with-sed-without-printing-the-surrounding-character/31479#31479) for more sed tricks.

```
command1 -p=aaa -v=bbb -i=4 | sed 's/^.*rate(\([0-9]*\)%).*$/\1/'
```

More flexible again than sed, is awk. Awk executes instructions for each line in a small imperative language. There are many ways to extract the rate here; I select the second fields (fields are delimited by whitespace by default), and remove all the characters in it that are not a digit.

```
command1 -p=aaa -v=bbb -i=4 | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

The next step, now that you've extracted the rate, is to pass it as an argument to `command2`. The tool for that is a [command susbtitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution). If you put a command inside `$(…)` (dollar-parenthesis), its output is substituted into the command line. The output of the command is split into separate words at each whitespace block, and each word is treated as a wildcard pattern; unless you want this to happen, put double quotes around the command substitution: `"$(…)"`. With the double quotes, the output of the command is used directly as a single parameter (the only transformation is that newlines at the end of the output are removed).

```
command2 -t "$(command1 -p=aaa -v=bbb -i=4 |
               sed 's/^.*rate(\([0-9]*\)%).*$/\1/')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` and it's PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. This allows you to utilize a lookbehind to match the value of rate, without inclusion of the string "rate" within your results when grepping for it.

#### Example

```
$ echo "rate (10%) - name: value - 10Kbps" | grep -oP '(?<=^rate \()\d+'
10
```

#### Details

The above `grep` works as follows:

- `-o` will return only what we're looking for, `\d+`, which is the digits within the parens.
- `-P` enables grep's PCRE feature
- `(?<=^rate \()` will only return strings that begin with "rate ("

#### command2

To catch the value of "rate" you can run `command1` like so:

```
$ rate=$(command 1 | grep -oP '(?<=^rate \()\d+'
```

Then for your 2nd command you'd simply use that variable.

```
$ command2 -t=${rate}
```

You could get fancy and make that all one line:

```
$ command2 -t=$(command1 | grep -oP '(?<=^rate \()\d+')
```

This will execute command1 inside the `$(..)` execution block, take its results and include them in command2's `-t=..` switch.

Comment: ... assuming it supports that option of course. It's not required by POSIX and not all greps have `-E`. But if it does it's a great feature of course.