# Can I chain pgrep with kill?

Tags: shell, pipe, arguments

I have noticed that `|` is used to send results of first command to the another. I would like to kill all processes that match a name.
This is what pgrep normally does:

```
$ pgrep name
5089
5105
```

And multiple arguments seem to work with `kill`:

```
sudo kill 5089 5105
```

But this is wrong:

```
pgrep name | kill
```

So how to do it properly?

Comment: `pkill`. And if that didn't exist, `kill $(pgrep ...)`.

Comment: I wasn't only asking about because of those specific commands but also to get better understanding of the command chaining. But as I can see from the question score, questions meant to understand are unwelcome...

Comment: If you want to make the question more general, and ensure it's not a duplicate, I can vote it up.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally deleted my previous comment.  I'm on a tablet and this site has really small buttons next to each other.

Comment: I was just saying that I downvoted because your question didn't seem to be asking anything you couldn't have learned from `man pgrep`.  The downvote button says it's for when a question shows no research effort, and I couldn't see any in your question.  Sorry if that seemed harsh.

Comment: The fact that I got to know xargs is quite beneficial to me - more than any reputation I could get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass the output of previous command to next as an argument](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this:

```
pgrep name | xargs kill
```

If you use `pgrep name | kill`, the ouput of `pgrep name` is feed to stdin of `kill`. Because `kill` does not read arguments from stdin, so this will not work.

Using `xargs`, it will build arguments for `kill` from stdin. Example:

```
$ pgrep bash | xargs echo
5514 22298 23079
```

Comment: Nothing to do with space versus newline.  Simply because kill doesn't read arguments on stdin.

Comment: @Mikel: My mistake, fixed.

Comment: is there a list of commands which xargs will build arguments for?

Comment: @alchemy any command you passed to xargs

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work for Tail ```sudo tail -F /var/log/syslog | xargs echo```. It will be extraordinarily handy for other things like Mail ```cat file | grep keyword | xargs echo | mail a@a.com``` without having to store the output of grep into a variable using Read, which can only do that in a subshell and buries the variable in Bash. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365222/346155)

Comment: If pgrep won't find the process, the parameter -f will not only search the processname for the expression but instead the whole line from ps. Example: `pgrep -f "yarn serve" | xargs kill`

Answer (score 35):

This should work:

```
pkill name
```

I also suggest reading the man page.

Answer (score 12):

To answer the general rather than the specific...

Pipes are for passing output from one program as *input* to another program.

It looks like you're trying to use one program's output as *command line arguments* to another program, which is different.

To do that, use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

For example if you want to run

```
sudo kill 5089 5105
```

And you have a command `pgrep name` that outputs `5089 5105`

You put them together like

```
sudo kill $(pgrep name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope this will help other beginners too.