# bash - get pid for a script using the script filename

Tags: shell-script, scripting, process

I have two scripts:

- `running_script`
- `script_one`

I need to get the PID for the/any instances of `running_script` running under a username, and then `pkill` to stop the `running_script` and daughter processes.

We expected something like:

```
ps -fu will | grep running_script
```

to find the `running_script` process(es).  However checking the PID against the ps command output show that the *cmd* as: "bin/bash" for the `running_script` process.

`running_script` runs as a detached process(`&` operator) which starts `script_one`.  I print the PID-s at the start to compare with `ps` command's output.

```
running_script  &
echo $! -- $BASHPID
```

In the real use-case, we won't have PIDs for some `running_script` processes running.  Also, `script_one` may or may not be a detached process from the `running_script` parent.

For the purposes of the exercise, `script_one` just does loops.

```
while [ true ]
do
    echo "  $0 - 35sec ..."
    sleep 35
done
```

However that's just the example.  The requirement is to get PID for the parent, `running_script` process(es).

Is there an option on `ps` or another command that can give me the name of the script file and the PID?  Or a method to set a name that *can* be searched for?

In the final use-case, there could be several instances of `running_script` so picking them out by name seems the best option to date.

### example

I thought it might help to show what the `ps` command shows, since most responses appear to think that's going to work.  I ran this example just a while ago.

```
$  ./running_script &
$  echo $! - $BASHPID
9047 - 3261
$  ps -ef | grep will

  UID     PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
  will   8862  2823  0 22:48 ?        00:00:01 gnome-terminal
  will   8868  8862  0 22:48 ?        00:00:00 gnome-pty-helper
  will   8869  8862  0 22:48 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
* will   9047  3261  0 22:55 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash
  will   9049  9047  0 22:55 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash
  will   9059  2886  0 22:56 pts/0    00:00:00 man pgrep
  will   9070  9059  0 22:56 pts/0    00:00:00 pager -s
  will  10228  9049  0 23:31 pts/2    00:00:00 sleep 35
  will  10232  8869  0 23:31 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -ef
  will  10233  8869  0 23:31 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto william
```

I have marked PID #9047, is simply shows:
  - will   9047  3261  0 22:55 pts/2    00:00:00 **/bin/bash**

Is there something like a a "*jobname*" attribute I could set on linux?

Comment: Would it be enough to get the PID of the parent process of `script1`?

Comment: In the interest of saving some time, every ps option shows "bash/bash",  NOT "running_script" when `running_script` is stared from the command line /terminal.

Comment: I'm testing these with v4.3.11(1)-release on linux mint 17.  The requirement is for the PID of running_script.  There is a (good) compliance reason for that requirement stemming from the hardware and software systems already running.

Comment: `ps --version` -->  "procps-ng version 3.3.9"

Answer (score 26):

Try `pgrep -f running_script` -- the -f option uses the whole command line to match against, not just the process name

Comment: The result is a null (or no output).   That's on gnu bash: v4.3.11(1)-release

Comment: Add `-l` (`--list-name`) to pgrep to name those processes.  E.g., for running script `claws2postgres.sh`, `pgrep -l -f claws2postgres` returns `23538 claws2postgres.`.

Comment: To immediately kill the found process use `pgrep -f "searchterm" | xargs kill`. Credits to user @cuonglm. Read his explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138206/295748).

Comment: To immediately kill, use `pkill` that takes exactly the same arguments as pgrep.

Answer (score 6):

`ps -o pid,args -C bash | awk '/running_script/ { print $1 }'`

This uses `ps` to get the pid and args for all bash processes, then uses awk to print the pid (field 1) of the matching process.

BTW, `ps -o pid,args -C bash` gives you the pid and the name of the script file you asked for - the script's name is in the args of the `bash` command.

If you're going to use `ps` rather than `pgrep` at least use its full capabilities rather than the extraordinarily ugly `ps ... | grep -v grep | grep | awk` construct.  The last `grep` isn't even needed as `awk` can perform the pattern match.  In fact, neither of the greps are needed as awk can do it all: `ps ax | awk '! /awk/ && /myprocessname/ { print $1}'`

Comment: The result is a null (or no output),  gnu bash: v4.3.11(1)-release.  The output of the ps command is: 9047 /bin/bash
 9049 /bin/bash, 8869 bash.  I suppose PID 8869 is the parent (mother of all) bash processes.  May be there's a different result if the `running_script` command is run from a script or something(??) rather than from the terminal (shell).

Comment: What version of `ps` are you running?  Try `ps --version`.  Both `ps -ef` and `ps -o args` are supposed to show the full command line, including arguments.   And do you have any of the Environment Variables mentioned near  the end of `man ps` set?

Comment: I put version in the question: "procps-ng version 3.3.9".  The mint system monitor shows the same information.  It probably uses ps (too anyway).  However the process pseudo device  only shows bash/bash -- Which leads me to believe it is it is bash setting the command information.

Comment: yep, you're right.  `bash` changes its args in `ps`.   I'll try to find out if there's a way of getting `ps` to show the real args.  In the meantime, you could try something like this if you are running on linux `ps h -o pid -C bash | xargs -IXX grep -sEl 'running_script' /proc/XX/cmdline | sed -re 's:/proc/([^/]*)/.*:\1:'`

Comment: FYI, `bash` only changes its name in `ps` if you run the script as `bash scriptname.sh`.  If you run it as just `./scriptname.sh` (or `/path/to/scriptname.sh`) then the script's real name will appear in `ps`

Comment: It also does it if you misuse `env` as in `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.  Yet another reason why using `env` like that is broken and why the python crowd should stop recommending it.

Comment: The Env is clean.  I may need to resort to writing a tmp file as suggested.  BUT that means a file for every process instance ... oy ve!

Comment: the PID file idea is a good one, but you should probably use `/var/run` or `/run` rather than `/tmp`.  That's what they're for.  Otherwise grep it out of `/proc/*/cmdline` as i suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep <script_name> | awk '{print $2}'
```

The above command will give the PID for the script_name. Also you can have the script write a temporary file with its running PID.

To save the [current PID](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters), add a line inside the script:

```
echo $$>/tmp/script_pid.tmp
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `ps -ef | grep -v grep | awk '/script_name/ {print $2}'`. With `pgrep` you avoid the nasty `grep -v grep`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# pidofargs.sh
# get process id by first argument of a process
# using `ps -eo pid,args` and `read -a`

# sample use: pidofargs.sh python /usr/bin/youtube-dl

search_grep="$1" # first filter
search_arg1="$2" # second filter

# first filter
ps -eo pid,args | grep "$search_grep" | while read pid args
do
  read -a arg < <(echo "$args")

  # pid    = process id
  # arg[0] = executable file of process
  # arg[1] = first argument of process

  # second filter
  if [[ "${arg[1]}" == "$search_arg1" ]]
  then
    # success
    echo $pid
    break
  fi

done
```