# Piping output of a command into grep and then into another command

Tags: shell, grep, pipe

I am taking output of one script, then piping this putput to grep and piping the output of grep into another script:

```
./script1 | grep 'expr' | ./script2
```

However, the second script never gets any input. Again, nothing gets printed when I substitute `script2` with `cat` and `script1` with `ping`:

```
ping localhost | grep localhost | cat
```

Same thing happens if I replace `grep` with `awk`:

```
ping localhost|awk '{print $1}'|cat
```

What is going on?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503197/130767

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`grep` is buffering (because it determines that its output isn’t a terminal; strictly speaking, this is the C library’s behaviour).

To disable this, run it with `unbuffer -p` (the `-p` is necessary for `unbuffer` to read from its standard input):

```
ping localhost | unbuffer -p grep localhost | cat
```

or tell `grep` to buffer by line (if it supports this):

```
ping localhost | grep --line-buffered localhost | cat
```

Comment: TY kindly for `--line-buffered` flag, since I do not have rights to install `unbuffer` on the target machine

Comment: Note: even without modifying buffer behaviour, grep will output all remaining output when script1 exits.

Comment: [`unbuffer -p` has quite a few issues](/q/760143) though.