# Redirect output to one file, while simultaneously filtering output to another using grep

Tags: grep, logs, tee

I have a process running that spits out a line of data every second. I want to output all the output to 'output.txt', but also output lines that have @ to a different file 'emails.txt'. I tried something like below,but the grep part doesn't work.

```
myProgrram | pee 'tee output.raw 2>&1' 'grep @ > email.txt'
```

Any ideas on how to improve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, what's `pee`!?

Comment: @tripleee [pee is like tee but for pipes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pee)

Comment: @steeldriver - the usual answer to that question is _"`pee` will split the output into multiple streams..."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who have responded - The following code worked

```
myProgram | pee 'tee -a output.txt' 'grep  --line-buffered @ > emails.txt'
```

- I also wanted the program to print to the console and "tee" does that, along with appending output.txt
- Use of unbuffered: [Piping output of a command into grep and then into another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440878/piping-output-of-a-command-into-grep-and-then-into-another-command)

Answer (score 15):

Here is one solution:

```
myprogram 2>&1 | tee output.txt | grep --line-buffered @ > emails.txt
```

Explanation:

- `stdin` is "standard in" (file descriptor number `0`).
- `stdout` is "standard out" (file descriptor number `1`).
- `stderr` is "standard error" (file descriptor number `2`).
- `2>&1` redirects anything that is sent to `stderr` to `stdout`.
- `|` pipes `stdout` on the left side to `stdin` on the right side.
- `tee output.txt` does two things at the same time:

  - writes `stdin` to `output.txt`
  - passes on `stdin` to `stdout`.
- `|` pipes `stdout` to `stdin`.
- `grep --line-buffered @` picks out any line with `@` from `stdin` and sends it to `stdout`.
- `> emails.txt` writes whatever is on `stdin` to `emails.txt`.

The `--line-buffered` flag makes `grep` use line buffering on output which can cause a performance penalty but ensures that *all* output will be printed to the file.