# How do I redirect output of command into ls?

Tags: shell, osx

I have a problem with redirections :

```
$ which python3
```

gives me

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

and

```
$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

gives me

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  9  5 fév 18:30 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -> python3.7
```

but

```
which python3 | ls -l
```

don't gives me the same result.

Do you know why ? And what is the right command for redirection ?

I'm using OSX.

I have to say that the following question [pass the output of previous command to next as an argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument) may be the same as this one, but if I look the answers that were given, there I'm lost. To be useful, they require more advanced knowledge or study than those given here.

Comment: I've updated the list of duplicates to some other better (IMHO) questions on the same topic.  Especially [Redirecting the content of a file to the command "echo"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/63658) mirrors your question quite well as `echo` behaves like `ls` with regards to (not) reading its standard input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ls` does not take input from standard in, but only from arguments:

Try `ls -l "$(which python3)"`

Answer (score 12):

`ls` does not read from the pipe.  In fact, `ls` does not use its standard input at all.

Instead, you have to pass the thing you'd like to run `ls -l` on via the command line of `ls`:

```
ls -l "$( which python3 )"
```

This uses a command substitution on the command line of `ls -l` which will expand to the output of the `which` command.  This will then be used as a command line argument for `ls`.

Alternatively:

```
ls -l "$( command -v python3 )"
```

Related:

- [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 7):

Other answers are good, but this is also handy:

```
which python3 | xargs ls -l
```

`xargs` gets values from `stdin` and appends them as command-line argument to the specified program.

Comment: This is much the best answer in my view, easy to apply to similar and more general cases of command line usage and output redirection. Thanks @jick.

Comment: This answer doesn't behave weirdly if you're passing quotes " in args, +1