# Can I pipe stdout to the middle of a command with emacs?

Tags: pipe, arguments, stdout

The command

```
emacs -nw foo -f org-mode
```

opens the file `foo` in `emacs` in `org-mode`.

Now, suppose that the filename `foo` is the output of a script. How could I pipe to my command?

So, I'm trying to get something like

```
echo foo | emacs -nw {GET OUTPUT HERE} -f org-mode
```

to work. Is this possible?

EDIT: This question has been voted to close, but the answer referenced doesn't work and wasn't tested by the user who voted to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass the output of previous command to next as an argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument)

Comment: @muru I read the question and answer you've referenced and don't understand how it helps me with my question.

Comment: @muru I looked at this and can't figure out how it solves my problem. Maybe you can help?

Comment: `echo foo | xargs -I {} emacs -nw {} -f org-mode`, or as alnx suggested, `emacs -nw "$(echo foo)" -f org-mode`.

Comment: @muru `echo foo | xargs -I {} emacs -nw {} -f org-mode` returns an error for me. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: `emacs: standard input is not a tty`

Comment: @muru If you didn't test, then why did you say the command would work and vote to close?

Comment: because those are the standard ways to use some command's outputs as the argument of another command. If you have a specific error with some of them, then you should include that in your post, which you haven't done at all. By the way: the method worked fine - `emacs` was run with the input as argument. You problem is that emacs doesn't like working in a pipeline, which means the idea behind your entire question is broken. Use a better editor

Comment: @muru You suggested `echo foo | xargs -I {} emacs -nw {} -f org-mode` and now you're saying that my question is broken. The existence of an answer and my question being "broken" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @muru Why not just post an answer that explains the flaws in my question so we can all learn from the problem? Despite the comments, I'm still confused why my problem isn't solvable.

Comment: @muru Command substitution is not the same as piping, which is what my question is explicitly about. If "broken" is not mutually exclusive from "solvable", then I don't understand what the adjective "broken" means.

Comment: Ok, let me try again: The `xargs` method there works in this aspect: the output of the command is used as an argument and `emacs` is started with that argument. In as much as this is your question, *the method works* - you can use stdout in the middle of a command. Try, say, `echo` or `cat` or `vim`, and you'll see the effect. The error you're getting is this: **After `emacs` has been started with that argument**, it sees that the input is a pipe, and it breaks. So the problem in the question has been solved, and now you have a new problem, which breaks your overall idea. Is that clearer?

Comment: @muru I don't understand why `emacs` behaves differently than the other commands. Why? This is totally not obvious.

Comment: Emacs is an OS that expects input to be connected to a terminal and doesn't work otherwise. Vim, for example, also expects the same thing, complains, but still works.

Comment: @muru I didn't know Emacs was an OS. I thought emacs was a text editor.

Comment: That's [an old joke.](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/wv3e8/finally_emacs_has_a_decent_texteditor/).

Comment: FWIW `echo foo | xargs -I{} emacs -t /dev/tty -nw {} -f org-mode` appears to work (no idea if there are other implications though)

Comment: Note, many emacs users keep the editor running permanently and connect to it with [emacsclient](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) when you want to edit a new file. You can set `EDITOR=emacsclient....` in various ways, see the link.

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using a subshell (as suggested in the comments):

```
emacs -nw $(<COMMAND GOES HERE>) -f org-mode
```

For example

```
emacs -nw $(echo foo) -f org-mode
```

Will open "foo" in org-mode

Comment: This would require that I already know the command. It would be nice to be able to pipe in from an arbitrary command with the same line of code.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I don't understand what you're saying there. You can use arbitrary commands in command substitution.

Comment: For instance, say I want my environment variable to be `$EDITOR=emacs -nw {my file} -f org-mode`. I can't use `$EDITOR=emacs -nw $(??) -f org-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `read` to get the filename from the pipe and then pass it as a variable to your command.

For example, using a shell function (probably not the best name for it, maybe you can think of something better):

```
emacspipe () {
    local filename
    read filename
    emacs -nw "$filename" -f org-mode
}
```

Then you can use:

```
$ echo foo | emacspipe
```

But using command substitution `$(...)` like the other answer suggests is definitely a more appropriate way to accomplish the same. If you have a command you can pipe to something, you can just as easily run it in a `$(...)` block and pass the resulting filename as an argument to the script or function starting emacs...