# Pass the output from previous command to next command

Tags: linux, shell, sort

I have two for loops below which creates final output as the sorted file,but I  want to merge into one for loop only

```
for i in *.txt; do
    cut -f 5,10 $i >$i.txt.out
done

###sorting

for i in *.txt.out; do
    sort -k1,1 $i >$i.sort
done
```

I tried merging the two loops into one by redirecting the output from the first for loop using pipe.
I tried one of the method from this post ([Pass the output of previous command to next as an argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument)) but not able to get the desired result.

```
for i in *.txt; do
    cut -f 5,10 $i >$i.txt.out | xargs -I{} sort -k1,1  {} >$i.sort
done
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for name in *.txt; do
    cut -f 5,10 -- "$name" | sort -k 1,1 >"$name.sort"
done
```

This would combine the effect of the two initial loops while getting rid of the use of the intermediate files.

I did some small modifications:

- Quoting of the expansion of all variables, because [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- Using a better name for the loop variable.
- Delimiting the variable from the `cut` command using `--` to signal the end of options, in case the filename in `$name` starts with a dash.

One could also have used `sort -k 1,1 -o "$name.sort"` in place of the `sort` command above, to let the `sort` utility create the output file rather than the shell (minor difference).

---

The `xargs` utility is often used *instead of* a loop:

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c 'cut -f 5,10 -- "$1" | sort -k 1,1 >"$1.sort"' sh "{}"
```

... but here it just makes thing more complicated (the command above would have issues handling filename containing newlines).

Your command

```
cut -f 5,10 $i >$i.txt.out | xargs -I{} sort -k1,1  {} >$i.sort
```

would do the `cut` and save the output to `$i.txt.out` (with `$i` expanded).  The `xargs` command would get no input due to the output of `cut` being redirected to a file.  If you hadn't redirected the output of `cut`, `xargs` would have executed `sort` with the *contents* of the files as arguments rather than with the filenames.  This is not what you want (you want to pass the output of `cut` as *data* into `sort`).