# How to tail the last 4 modified files?

Tags: bash, terminal

I feel like I am missing something very simple and I was wondering if it possible to sow the last few lines of the last 4 modified files. I tried something like this

```
tail | ls -lt | head -5
```

but I think I should iterate over `ls | -lt` result and apply tail to it and I am not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108797

Comment: @Panki I think most of the discussion tells me that getting the file names to iterate over from `ls` is a bad idea. So I should probably think about a better approach

Comment: this seems a bit more relevant. https://askubuntu.com/questions/684220/how-to-list-the-last-modified-files-in-a-specific-directory-recursively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I start, it’s generally considered bad practice to use the output of `ls` as input for something else; a common flaw being that it may not work as intended for files containing white space/new line in their name.

With that limitation in mind, you will probably find that `ls | something` will work OK most of the time.

You are heading in the right direction with your command, here is one solution with the above caveat about `ls` limitations:

```
ls -t | head -5 | xargs tail
```

This will throw a non fatal error if there are subdirectories in your listing.

Comment: My files are have normal names with just periods and underscores. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In the `zsh` shell, the four most recently modified regular files in the current directory can be had by the globbing pattern

```
./*(.Dom[1,4])
```

... where `./*` matches all names in the current directory and the parenthesis modifies the behavior of the matching.  The `.` makes the `*` match *only* regular files while `D` makes it also match hidden names (as with the `dotglob` shell option enabled in the `bash` shell).  The `om` orders the resulting list of names by modification timestamp and the `[1,4]` picks out the first four names.

To call `tail` on these files:

```
tail ./*(.Dom[1,4])
```

From the `bash` shell:

```
zsh -c 'tail ./*(.Dom[1,4])'
```

If you want consider all files in the current directory or anywhere below it, then use

```
zsh -c 'tail ./**/*(.Dom[1,4])'
```

The `**` pattern works in a similar manner to the same globbing pattern in `bash` when the `globstar` shell option is enabled, i.e. it matches down into subdirectories recursively.  The `D` in the glob qualifier would make the `**` match into subdirectories with hidden names.

Comment: unfortunately I do not ave access to zsh. As in I can not install zsh as this is not my computer.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you

```
find . -type f -mmin -5 -ls | tail -4
```

In place of `.`     =>    add your target directory path

This above command will get you the last modified 5 minutes ago files , if want you can increase your last modified minutes from 5 minutes to your need `eg: 15min , 20min , 60min`

Answer (score 1):

If there's no subdirectories, then this should work, even if the files have spaces in their names. It will however fail if the files have newlines in their names.

`ls -1t  | head -4 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0  head -10`

Unfortunately, it will fail if there is subdirectories. If there is, then this should work

`find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1t  | head -4 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0  head -10`