# Passing output of one command to another

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to pass output of one command to other:

```
ls -lt *.txt | tail -n 3 | cat
```

I want to list all `.txt` files, take last 2, and display their contents using `cat`, but this is incorrect way. How can I achieve this? I referred to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108797/431721 and tried using `cat $( ls -lt *.txt | tail -n 3)`, but not working. Any comments?

Comment: so, how can I display all/last n lines of the last 3 files found by `ls`?

Comment: ls *.txt | tail -2 | xargs -I xx cat xx  may do what you want.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#:~:text=Why%20you%20shouldn't%20parse%20the%20output%20of%20ls(1)&text=In%20its%20default%20mode%2C%20if,a%20newline%20in%20its%20name.)

Comment: What is the end goal, are you just trying to concatenate two random files or are you looking for specific files?

Comment: @jesse_b end goal is to I display all/last n lines of the last 3 files found by `ls`

Comment: Yes but you should not use ls so we need to find a better way to determine these files, which is most likely globbing, and these files will be in random order.  Do you want 3 random files or 3 specific files?

Comment: You know that is actually getting you the 3 oldest files not the 3 newest right?

Comment: Edited: last 3 *.txt files modified, so using `ls -tr *.txt`

Comment: Someone took the time to downvote almost all answers ️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work through it one step at a time:

```
$ ls -lt *.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 stew stew 18 Feb  5 19:53 file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 stew stew 18 Feb  5 19:53 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 stew stew 18 Feb  5 19:53 file1.txt
```

We have three files, but you only wanted two.  Let's `tail` it:

```
$ ls -lt *.txt | tail -n 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 stew stew 18 Feb  5 19:53 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 stew stew 18 Feb  5 19:53 file1.txt
```

Ok, that's good but we really only want two filenames.  `ls -l` isn't the right tool, we can just use `ls`:

```
$ ls -t *.txt | tail -n 2
file2.txt
file1.txt
```

Then put that output into `cat` as arguments with `$()`:

```
$ cat $(ls -t *.txt | tail -n 2)
content of file 2
content of file 1
```

---

You asked about how to use an alias for `ls -lthr`.  `-l` doesn't really work well because it prints more than filenames.  `-h` only makes sense if `-l` is there.  So here's an example for `ls -tr`:

```
$ alias lt='ls -tr'
$ cat $(lt *.txt | tail -n 2)
content of file 2
content of file 3
```

If you have something in your `.bashrc` like `alias ls='ls -lthr'`, then you can use `command ls` or `env ls`.  If you want something else that handles odd characters (such as newlines) in files too, here's an example using `find` instead:

```
cat $(find . -name '*.txt' | tail -n 2)
```

However ordering may not be the same as with your `ls` solution and it will also search subdirectories.

Comment: How to use any aliases for `ls -lthr` with flags inside `$()`?

Comment: You wouldn't want `ls -l` for reasons I mentioned in the post.  `ls -h` only works with `-l`, so don't use this in this case either.  I've updated the question to answer about using `ls -tr` as an alias

Comment: This will fail with file names with spaces.

Comment: @Stewart your command `cat $(find . -name '*.txt' | tail -n 2)` gives me `cat: ./foo: No such file or directory` for file `'foo bar.txt'`

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity ah, I see.  You're right.  We can solve this with `find -print0` and `xargs -0`, but then we lose the `tail`.  I do like kulsalananda's answer here.

Answer (score 3):

To correctly deal with all possible filenames (including those with newlines), the following would call `cat` for the two least recently modified files, with the oldest file being handled last, using the `zsh` shell:

```
cat ./*.txt(.om[-2,-1])
```

The following would `cat` the two most recently modified files, with the most recently modified being handled first:

```
cat ./*.txt(.om[1,2])
```

Here, the `(.om[1,2])` after the `./*.txt` globbing pattern is a *glob qualifier*.  The `.` in the qualifier makes the pattern only match plain files (not directories etc.).  The `om` orders the files by modification timestamp (`Om` would reverse the order).  The `[1,2]` picks out only the first two elements of the resulting list.  Negative indexes here would count from the end of the list.

From the `bash` shell, using `zsh` as any other utility:

```
zsh -c 'cat ./*.txt(.om[-2,-1])'
```

and

```
zsh -c 'cat ./*.txt(.om[1,2])'
```

respectively.

Comment: Oh, much nicer than parsing `ls`!  This uses `zsh` language to avoid the pipes between different tools.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have GNU coreutils ls:

```
eval "sorted=( $(ls -rt --quoting-style=shell-escape *.txt) )"
cat "${sorted[@]:0:3}"
```

it's not an ideal solution but it will create an array with the txt files in your current directory sorted by time modified and then cat the first 3.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this:

```bsh
arr=("$(find ~+ -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%T@\000%p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 2 | cut -d '' -f2)")

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

---

```bsh
# create an array from the command
arr=("$( \

  # use `find` to fetch the files and the timstamp
  # using null as separator
  find ~+ -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%T@\000%p\n" | \
  
  # sort
  sort -nr | \
  
  # retrieve the first 2 files
  head -n 2 | \
  
  # retrieve only the file names
  cut -d '' -f2 \
)")

# print the array
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Doesn't work with files with newlines in the name.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply execute the following command in one line:

```
$ ls *.txt | tail -2 | xargs cat
```

**Explanation:**

Create three test files:

```
tc@user1:~$ echo "first file reads 1" > file1.txt
tc@user1:~$ echo "second file reads 2" > file2.txt
tc@user1:~$ echo "third file reads 3" > file3.txt
```

Verify files were created:

```
tc@user1:~$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r--    1 tc       staff           19 Feb  5 18:58 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 tc       staff           20 Feb  5 18:58 file2.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 tc       staff           19 Feb  5 18:58 file3.txt
```

List all text files, then read the contents of the last two files by use of piping:

```
tc@user1:~$ ls *.txt | tail -2 | xargs cat
second file reads 2
third file reads 3
```

Comment: Gives error `cat: invalid option -- 'r'`

Comment: @ewr3243 thats because you modified his command and added the `-l` option to `ls`.  But this also wouldn't work anyway.