# Linux Bash Script Parsing Unknown output with Known Delimeter

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm writing a recon shell script and I would like to parse the output of odat sidguesser so i can save only the found SID's into a file or variable.
For example. I have the string;

```
[+] SIDs found on the 10.10.10.82:1521 server: XE,XEXDB
```

What I'm trying to do is parse this output so only XE,XEXDB remains so I can store it in a file or variable to further enumerate / run odat passwordguesser with the SID.
How can i use sed or awk or grep etc... to get all valid SID's without knowing how many will be found?
I'm able to get the SID's by doing,

```
cat oracle-sid.txt | grep "server:" | rev | cut -d " " -f 1 | rev
```

This works for my purposes since XE,XEXDB is all considered 1 string and i can write more logic to loop through it etc.... However, In the case where the SID's were separated by spaces, How would one go about parsing every SID or string after the word/delimeter, "server:" ?

Comment: Is it fair to say that all the text up to and including `server: ` is useless to you, and you just want the part that comes afterward, as-is?  Or do you need the SIDs broken out one by one?

Comment: For the first part, eliminating the useless part of the string, your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern).  For the second part, splitting up a string based on a delimiting character, your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash).

Comment: Is `XE,XEXDB` one of these SID things you mention, or is it two of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -n -e 's/^.*server: //p' oracle-sid.txt
XE,XEXDB
```

On matching lines, the `sed` script deletes everything from the beginning of the line to "server: " (including the trailing space), and then prints the modified line.  Non-matching lines are ignored (i.e. not printed).

If you want to keep the IP address and port as well:

```
$ sed -e -e 's/^.* \([0-9.:]\+\) server: /\1\t/p' oracle-sid.txt
10.10.10.82:1521        XE,XEXDB
```

This will do the same as the first version, but include the IP:Port and a TAB character.