# Parse value from different JSON strings (No jq)

Tags: awk, sed, json

I'm using bash script that needs to read the JSON output and parse a value from different JSON variables or strings. Here's the sample output. It needs to read the value next to the `Content` or from any other variable. Such as,

Lookup `Content` and be able to print `Value1`.

Lookup `DeviceType` and be able to print `Value4`

Sample Ouput:
`{"Content":"Value1","CreationMethod":"Value2","database":"Value3","DeviceType":"Value4"}`

I tried the combination of sed and awk `sed 's/["]/ /g' | awk '{print $4}'`, but only if the position of `Content` remains the same in the output. otherwise in the different JSON output, the positioning of `Content` changes that puts the value out of scope thus `awk '{print $4}'` picks up the wrong value.

Comment: "No jq" - no good JSON parsing

Comment: This would be _trivial_ with `jq`, or any other JSON parser.  With `sed` and or `awk`, you would not only have to rely on the document always being formatted _exactly_ the same way, but also do your own string decoding in case the data is JSON encoded.

Comment: Is using bash a mandatory requirement?

Comment: Is Perl allowed?

Comment: You want to get the values only? Or would you want a specific output text? How's the lookup performed, with `grep`?

Comment: No "jq" and no "perl"

Comment: From the output, if it can grep ```"Content":``` and then only print the ```Value1```

Comment: Please looks here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/return-only-the-portion-of-a-line-after-a-matching-pattern

Comment: How about Python?  Any scripting language?  What is the reason for ruling out the most suitable tools for the job?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you correctly, with GNU `grep` and `tr`:

```
tr ',' '\n' < foo | grep -Po "(?<=Content\":\").*(?=\")"
```

Output:

```
Value1
```

With other keyword:

```
tr ',' '\n' < foo | grep -Po "(?<=database\":\").*(?=\")"

Value 3
```

---

Replace the commas for a new line:

```
tr ',' '\n'
```

---

Grep `-o` only `-P` perl like regex

```
grep -Po
```

---

Catch the pattern `("<keyword>:"")<value>(")` and print *only* `<value>`.

Comment: Or `s="Content"; grep -Po "(?<=$s\":\")[^\"]*" file`

Answer (score 0):

`jq`less and `perl`less sledgehammer using OP's intended `sed`/`awk`

```
s="Content"; sed 's/[{}"]//g' file | awk -v s=$s -F ":" -v RS=',' '($1 == s) {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I admit that this is awful...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="\"[^\"]+\""; RS=","; pat=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]} 
     $1 ~ pat {print $2} '       Content ex.json
"Value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ jq -r '.Content' file
Value1
$ jq -r '.DeviceType' file
Value4
```

There is no reason to not install `jq` to parse the JSON properly, safely, and without having to care about decoding JSON-encoded strings manually etc.

The `jq` utility [is available for download](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in a form that does not require root permissions for installation in your home directory (no external runtime dependencies).